# Convert string to integer inside body data in jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I stored jobID in variable as newID after create a job ,I try to pass this newID as integer ,I want to convert it as integer because when i create a job it return string ID ?

````
{"limit":100,"offset":0,"countryID":null,"experienceYear":null,"languageIdIn":[],"degreeLevel":null,"jobID":"${__groovy(newID)}"]}
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSON you need to remove the quotes around integer value

```
jobID":${newID}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your request body is not a valid JSON, you need to remove this unbalanced `]`, you can check it yourself using [online JSON validator tool](https://jsonlint.com/)
2. You need to remove quotation marks around `jobID` attribute value, see [JSON Data Types](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp) for more details
3. `${__groovy(newID)}` expression is syntactically incorrect, if `newID` is a JMeter Variable - you need to refer it using [`vars` shorthand for JMeterVariables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) class like:

Putting everything together:

```
{
  "limit": 100,
  "offset": 0,
  "countryID": null,
  "experienceYear": null,
  "languageIdIn": [
  ],
  "degreeLevel": null,
  "jobID": ${__groovy(vars.get('newID'),)}
}
```